# How can I use both /g and /i in regex to make my search repeat through the entire search as well as ignore case sensitivity in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove white space, comma, and digits from my string as well as ignore case sensitivity.
Below is my regex to this I am not able to use /i(to remove case sensitivity) and /g(repeat search) together in my expression.

> Regex expression

```
var str = "My age is 0, 0 si ega ym."
str.replace(/[,\s\d.]+/g,'')
```

Where shall I put /i in the above expression?

Comment: just add `i` after `g` `str.replace(/[,\s\d.]+/gi,'')`

Comment: `str.replace(/[,\s\d.]+/gi,'')`

Comment: None of `,\s\d\.` are case-sensitive anyway, so you could as well omit it

Comment: @MaheerAli thanks :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan thanks :)

Comment: @Bergi , Yes \s\d are not case sensitive. I only wanted to know how to use both g,i together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple flags in any order and put after the pattern(after the `/`).

---

```
/ pattern / flags
|   |     |   |__  Flags
|   |     |
|   |     |_______ End of regex literal
|   |     
|   |_____________ pattern to match
|
|_________________ start of regex literal
```

---

```
str.replace(/[,\s\d.]+/gi,'')
```

From [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2):

> Regular expressions have six optional flags that allow for functionality like global and case insensitive searching. These flags can be used separately or together in any order, and are included as part of the regular expression

Ref : [RegExp with flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2)